# React accessing innerhtml using ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

I cant access the inner html of my ellement using refs. The ref to my element is outputted, but the element.innerHTML is outputted as undefined, why is that?

```
const MyEditableComponent = ({ content }) => {
  const valueRef = useRef();

  const onContentChange = React.useCallback(evt => {
    const sanitizeConf = {
      allowedTags: ["b", "i", "a", "p"],
      allowedAttributes: {
        a: ["href"]
      }
    };
    const innerhtml = valueRef.current.innerHTML;
    console.log(valueRef.current)
    console.log(innerhtml)
    //setContent(sanitizeHtml(innerhtml, sanitizeConf))    
  }, [])

  return (
    <ContentEditable 
        ref = {valueRef}
        html={content}//inner html
        onChange={onContentChange}
        tagName="div"             
        style={{ overflowWrap: 'break-word', wordWrap: 'break-word', wordBreak: 'break-word', whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap', overflow: 'auto'
        }}
    />
  )
}
```

And can I write this in a better way?

Comment: Is `ContentEditable` from a lib? If so, which one?

Comment: ContentEditable from 'react-contenteditable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the ref, use the the event's target (the actual element) to get the value, which is the HTML ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/myeditablecomponent-p4eyms?file=/src/index.js)):

```
const MyEditableComponent = ({ content }) => {
  const onContentChange = (evt) => {
    const html = evt.target.value;
    console.log({ html });
    //setContent(sanitizeHtml(html, sanitizeConf))
  };

  return (
    <ContentEditable
      html={content} // innerHTML of the editable div
      onChange={onContentChange} // handle innerHTML change
      tagName="div"
    />
  );
};
```

If you need to a ref to get the html, set the ref using the [`innerRef` prop](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable#available-props). The `innerRef` prop set's the ref on the actual DOM element, and you can get the `innerHTML` from it (sandbox):

```
const MyEditableComponent = ({ content }) => {
  const valueRef = useRef();

  const onContentChange = () => {
    const html = valueRef.current.innerHTML;
    console.log({ html });
    //setContent(sanitizeHtml(html, sanitizeConf))
  };

  return (
    <ContentEditable
      innerRef={valueRef}
      html={content} // innerHTML of the editable div
      onChange={onContentChange} // handle innerHTML change
      tagName="div"
    />
  );
};
```